# Error in Merge Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, methods, merge

I made my own merge sort which has a method that allows only an ArrayList and a Comparator. My colleague requested that the tmp Array that I normally declared into the "merge" method must be declared into the first wrapper method (mergeSort). Now if I execute a test with 3 elements it doesn't work. Why?

```
public static < T > void mergeSort(ArrayList < T > array, Comparator < T > c) {
    int high = array.size()-1;
    sort(array, c, 0, high, new ArrayList < T > (high + 1));
  }  

  protected static < T > void sort(ArrayList < T > array, Comparator < T > c, int low, int high, ArrayList < T > tmp) {
    if (low < high) {
      int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
      sort(array, c, low, mid, tmp);
      sort(array, c, mid + 1, high, tmp);
      merge(array, c, low, mid, high, tmp);
    }
  }

  protected static < T > void merge(ArrayList < T > array, Comparator < T > c, int p, int mid, int q, ArrayList < T > tmp) {
    int i = p;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    for (; i <= mid && j <= q; k++) {
      if (c.compare(array.get(i), array.get(j)) < 0)
        tmp.add(k, array.get(i++));
      else
        tmp.add(k, array.get(j++));
    }
    if (i <= mid && j > q) {
      while (i <= mid)
        tmp.add(k++, array.get(i++));
    } else {
      while (j <= q)
        tmp.add(k++, array.get(j++));
    }
    for (k = 0; k < tmp.size(); k++)
      array.set(k + p, tmp.get(k));
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific than "it doesn't work". Give a specific example of input and output that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `tmp` `ArrayList` was previously local to the `merge` method, this implies that after moving it to the `mergeSort` call, it should be cleared before being used in each call to `merge`:

```
protected static < T > void merge(ArrayList < T > array, Comparator < T > c, int p, int mid, int q, ArrayList < T > tmp) {
    tmp.clear();
    ...
}
```

Without clearing it, you'll keep adding elements to it in each call to `merge`. It will just keep growing, and you might re-use obsolete elements of it.